# Text to speech Web Application How to open in browser

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech

I create the code for text to speech.
I want it to open web browser how to do this??
I am using windows 7 OS.
I also download xampp.

```
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            synthesizer.Volume = 100;  // 0...100
            synthesizer.Rate = -2;     // -10...10

            // Synchronous
            synthesizer.Speak("Hello World");

            // Asynchronous
            synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Hello World");



        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add this namespace

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Then, run this code which will find the default web browser and launch it.

```
    Process p = new Process();
    string browser = string.Empty;
    RegistryKey key = null;
    try
    {
        key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"HTTP\shell\open\command", false);

        //trim off quotes
        browser = key.GetValue(null).ToString().ToLower().Replace("\"", "");
        if (!browser.EndsWith("exe"))
        {
            //get rid of everything after the ".exe"
            browser = browser.Substring(0, browser.LastIndexOf(".exe") + 4);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (key != null) key.Close();
    }
    p.StartInfo.FileName = browser;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://www.google.com";
    p.Start();
```